# Which FOSS label engine that supports shrink to fit label in polygon?

Tags: qgis, geoserver, labeling, mapserver, mapnik

I've not found a way to label features using shrink to fit label in polygon, i've tried Qgis, and searched on Geoserver, Mapserver and Mapnik, none of them supports this feature, i'm looking for any FOSS that could label features with that option.